# Docker caching - build is big even though I removed .git repo

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I ran these steps in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN git clone my-repo       # step 1
RUN some other stuff        # step 2
RUN rm -rf 'my-repo/.git'   # step 3
```

I thought this would reduce the size of the docker image, but it didn't seem to - is that because step 1 is a layer that cannot be downsized by step 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BMitch explained, this is how docker layer mechanism works. Removing files from previous layers does not reduce image size as layers data are immutable and actually there are not removed. Thus one option is to chain multiple actions in the same `RUN` command.

**Another option**, depending on the nature of the commands in step two, you may want to use [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

The concept is to split your build process in stages, each stage may derive from different image and you can use just a resource you are interested from a previous stage without inheriting size overhead from previous layers.

For example, if your git repo contains a maven project that generates a `.war` and your goal is to deploy this `war` in an app server on a docker container, your Dockerfile could be as follows:

```
FROM some_image_with_maven_installed AS builder
RUN git clone my-repo 
WORKDIR my_repo_dir
RUN mvn clean package

FROM some_image_with_app_server_installed
WORKDIR app_server_deployment_dir
COPY --from=builder /path_to_war/app.war .
RUN start_server
....
```

So you are only copying the `war` file to the server discarding everything from the builder stage.

I could be more specific for your case if you define the nature of `step 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Each `RUN` step will execute a command inside of a temporary container, and the resulting filesystem changes from that command are captured as an immutable layer. That layer may include instructions to delete files in previous layers, but those files are not deleted from the previous layers since they are immutable, and possibly reused among other images. E.g. you can delete files from the alpine or debian base image inside your created image, and that will not break every other image that has been created off of those images.

Therefore a best practice when designing Dockerfiles is to delete any temporary files inside the same step where those files are created. You'll often see this done by chaining commands like:

```
RUN git clone my-repo \
 && echo some other stuff \
 && rm -rf 'my-repo/.git'
```